# Grub boot sound from wav, ogg, etc?

Tags: boot, grub2

I was wondering... I want Grub to play a complex sound that isn't just made of beeps when it boots. I can't find any converter that can take a wav and spit out a beep script, and I don't know if I can possibly link Grub's INIT TUNE command to a file on the hard drive (in `usr/share/*`). Is it possible to do either of these things? (I'm trying to get the macOS boot sound to play on Grub boot.)

Comment: I would have thought someone somewhere would have written a conversion script. With regards to using the file directly, no. Grub runs before your OS and thus before any typical program that could be used to interpret an audio file. In fact, it runs before most device drivers which is why it uses the "beeps" instead of an attached audio system. Note that not all systems have the speaker required for this to work.

Comment: I've looked around for a conversion script... No such luck.

Answer (score 2):

**As stated by [Andrew Shum](https://askubuntu.com/users/549712/andrew-shum):**

> I would have thought someone somewhere would have written a conversion script. With regards to using the file directly, no. Grub runs before your OS and thus before any typical program that could be used to interpret an audio file. In fact, it runs before most device drivers which is why it uses the "beeps" instead of an attached audio system. Note that not all systems have the speaker required for this to work.

(I'm posting this as an answer so that it has reference to those who only are looking for questions with answers, but all credit goes to Andrew. Link above to his profile.)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a few things, and I've come to the conclusion that grub just can't do this. I've been able to convert PCM into the format grub wants with somewhat reasonable quality (5kHz with a bit depth of 1), but grub just can't keep time well enough for this to work. Maybe it's my motherboards fault instead, but the result is the same either way: it doesn't work.

Rapid arpeggios to simulate chords worked, but unfortunately that means the most we can get out of grub tunes is bad-sounding chords. I won't upload the script I used to generate either because there's really no point when it just *doesn't work*. Sorry.